# Unable to set user permissions correctly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My app allows anyone to view listings but not delete or edit - this works fine because if they try to do this they get an error message. **Sorry, this listing belongs to someone else.**

however when an existing user tries to edit  or delete his/her listing they created it should go to  the edit screen or should show the delete message but it gives the same error message **Sorry, this listing belongs to someone else.**

**PostController.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :check_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id


      if @post.save
        redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' 

      else
        render action: 'new' 

      end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update

      if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.'

      else
       render action: 'edit' 

      end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_url


  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:company, :contact, :email, :telephone, :website)
    end

    def check_user
      if current_user != @post.user_id
        redirect_to posts_url, alert: "Sorry, this contact belongs to someone else but you can view detalis by clicking on show"
      end
    end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base


    validates :company, :contact, :email, :telephone, :website, presence: true

    belongs_to :posts
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing `current_user` with an interger, `@post.user_id`, so it's always false. You want to do `current_user.id != @post.user_id`.

Do you know about `cancan`? https://github.com/ryanb/cancan
It's great to encapsulate all the logic for permissions, and very easy to use.

Lastly, you should look into `pry` (https://github.com/pry/pry), it's the best tool I know to debug.

Comment: yes working now , not familiar with cancan yet but sounds cool , thanks!